# передача данных из одного окна в другое JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, конструктор

Здесь на странице регистрации я хочу передать допустим имя в следующее окно вот так:

```
@FXML
private TextField nameFiled;

@FXML
private TextField colorField;

@FXML
private Button goServer;

@FXML
void initialize(){
    goServer.setOnAction(event -> {
        String name = nameFiled.getText();
        Client client;

        if (!nameFiled.getText().equals("")) {

            try {
                client = new Client(name);
                System.out.println(client);
                goServer.getScene().getWindow().hide();
                // Здесь я не очень понимаю, что я должен делать, я передал в конструктор имя человека
                WaitGame waitGame = new WaitGame(name);
                FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/waitGame.fxml"));

                loader.setController(waitGame);

                Parent page = FXMLLoader.load(waitGame.getClass().getResource("fxml/waitGame.fxml"));
                waitGame.initialize();
                Scene scene = new Scene(page, 1000, 720);
                Stage stage = new Stage();
                stage.setScene(scene);
                stage.showAndWait();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

В этом классе я создаю конструктор, так как я хочу передать имя из предыдущего класса. в предыдущем классе я в ручную вызывал `initialize`, т.к. у меня не вызывается он и у меня вылетает ошибка `NPE` в `labelNick.setText(name);`

```
public class WaitGame {
    private String name;

    public WaitGame(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @FXML
    private Button buttonReady;;

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<?> boxColor;

    @FXML
    private Label countReady;

    @FXML
    private Label labelNick;

    @FXML
    void initialize(){
        labelNick.setText(name);
        countReady.setText("1/10");
    }

}
```

В общем было бы неплохо обьяснить как нужно пользоваться конструктором и `initialize` вместе и в принципе если можете дайте комментарии по коду.

Comment: Пропишите Ваш контроллер в `fxml` и тогда Ваш `initialize` метод сработает. Что бы передать имя нужно, вытащить из  `FXMLLoader` контроллер и засетить нужные Вам данные в поля. 

Метод `initialize` вызывается самим JavaFX.

Answer (score 0):

```
WaitGame waitGame = new WaitGame(name);

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/waitGame.fxml"));

loader.setController(waitGame);
Pane mainPane = loader.load();

Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane, 1000, 720);
```